# Debugging XSLT in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: xslt, visual-studio, debugging, content-query-web-part

I'm trying to debug XSLT for CQWP.
I followed this [guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/carloshm/debugging-xslt-from-a-content-query-webpart).
So I'm able to retrieve the XML, and link the files temporarily together using xsl:import.
But then Visual Studio can't find the schema for
xmlns:cmswrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3/Publishing/runtime" and fails when I try to use templates as SafeImageUrl and DisplayTitle. The blog mention this, but I don't understand the workaround. And I have the same issue when I have to use ddwrt.
Is there no way I can import the schema files? I had a look around but found nothing.